# Filepicker REST API POST requests using a file with Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, post, database-migration, filepicker.io

I'm working on a data migration from MySQL to Postgres, from a db with images blobbed in a column to a new db where all images are uploaded to Filepicker. I'm looking to use the Filepicker REST API to convert this but keep being met with 400 Bad Requests when sending POST requests with these images. I can't find a clearly defined answer to this and am new to this area of work - hope someone's able to point me in the right direction.

I've the following code attempting this as part of a larger Kiba ELT migration (which I'm pretty sure is irrelevant to this qu.):

```
  # ***************
  # Image conversion
  # ***************

  # Write the old file to a temporary new one
  file = File.new("oldimages/oldimage#{row[:id]}.jpg", 'w')
  file.write(row[:image])
  file.close

  # Access this new file
  file = File.read("oldimages/oldimage#{row[:id]}.jpg")

  # Fix issue with invalid UTF8
  puts "Valid file encoding before conversion? " + file.valid_encoding?.to_s
  if !file.valid_encoding?
    file = file.encode("UTF-16be", :invalid=>:replace, :replace=>"?").encode('UTF-8')
  end
  puts "Valid file encoding after conversion? " + file.valid_encoding?.to_s

  # Set URI
  uri = "https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3?key=#{ENV['FILEPICKER_API_KEY']}"
  puts "URI being used: " + uri

  # Make post request to Filepicker sending the file to be uploaded
  # This works: curl -X POST -F fileUpload=@oldimages/oldimage1.jpg https://www.filepicker.io/api/store/S3\?key\=ENV['FILEPICKER_API_KEY']
  # Also works as { "url" => SOME_IMAGE_URL }
  # ...... BUT THIS DOESN'T WORK
  params = { "fileUpload" => "@oldimages/oldimage#{row[:id]}.jpg" }
  puts "Here the params: " + params.to_s
  res = RestClient.post uri, params


  # Convert the response into a hash and grab the new Filepicker URL
  puts "Response: " + res.to_s
  puts "Response FP URL: " + eval(res.to_s)[:url]
  fp_url = eval(res.to_s)[:url]

  # Assign the Filepicker URL to the image
  newrow[:filepicker_url] = fp_url
  puts "Newrow FP URL AFTER assignment: " + newrow[:filepicker_url]

  # ***************
  # end image conversion
  # ***************
```

So, I can get this to work by passing an image's URL as params for the post request, and on the command line using a file and cURL. However, I can't get this Ruby to find the file without getting a Bad Request. I feel like I've tried countless iterations of this code in an attempt to find a working solution, but to no avail so far.

Filepicker docs on the subject [here](https://www.filepicker.com/documentation/file_ingestion/rest_api/storing).

Could it be passing the file path as a string to the params is breaking this?

Any help, I'm eternally grateful. Let me know if you could use any extra code....

Steve.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code shared here it might be how you're submitting the command to filepicker.

Tried to check out https://github.com/rest-client/ but for some reason it is down.

Iff you want to reach me directly please shoot an email to dylan@filepicker.com

Dylan